# Append row 1 & 2 together, then row 3 & 4, and so on in excel\text file

Tags: excel, powershell, append, row

I have a spreadsheet that contains building details, but the building details are spread over 2 rows, so row 1 & 2 contain the building info for building 1, then rows 3 & 4 contain details for building 2.  Is there a way to append row 2 to row 1, and then row 4 to row 3, an so on.

The source file is currently a .xlsx, but can be saved as .csv or txt if easier to work with.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You need use `-ReadCount` key at `Get-Content`, it specifies how many lines of content are sent through the pipeline at a time. The default value is 1. A value of 0 (zero) sends all of the content at one time.
Code:

```
Get-Content -Path "path to your file" -ReadCount 2 |ForEach-Object{$_ -join ""}
```

Comment: I believe OP is looking at the worksheet, not a text file.

Comment: save it to .csv or .txt and work with it like in your question.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work, but need to develop it, is there a way to get a "," or ";" between each join, so that i can import into excel and each join is in a separate cell.

Comment: just add `ForEach-Object{$_ -join ";"}` or `ForEach-Object{$_ -join ","}`

Answer (score 0):

Didn't see your file attached but here is an idea:

1. Use the offset function to copy your even rows after your odd rows, assuming your data starts in A1 in the cell after your last cell with data in column A: +offset(A1,1,1,1,1) and copy paste for as many cells as you need.
2. Drag this down for all your rows.
3. After your last cell of the offset data in column A put a 0 and in column B put a 1. Drag this down for all your rows so you have a 0 for the rows you want and a 1 for all rows you don't want.
4. Filter out all your rows with 1 and delete them using Ctrl + g and click special then click visible cells only and delete all the rows defined by 1.

Hope this helps